# Under what conditions $E|X_n-X|\rightarrow 0$, given $X_n\rightarrow X$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expectation

Given we have a sequence of random variables $X_n\rightarrow X$, under what conditions can we say that $E|X_n-X|\rightarrow 0$?

I know that $X_n\rightarrow X$ implies that $|X_n-X|\rightarrow 0$, but this alone is not enough. The dominated convergence theorem for expectation implies the desired result but that assumes that $|X_n|\leq Z\in L^1$.

Also if $\|X_n-X\|_\infty \rightarrow 0$, that should do it.

Is there a necessary condition?

Comment: $X_n \to X$ in what sense?  In probability?  Almost surely?

Comment: I was assuming for all $\omega\in\Omega$, i.e. surely, but if other conditions imply it then I am open to them. I am just trying to get a full picture of the different convergence conditions.

Comment: If $X_n\rightarrow X$ in $L^2$, then $E|X_n-X|\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: What is definition of convergence in $L^2$, is it equivalent to $|X_n-X|^2\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: It means that $E\left((X_n-X)^2\right)\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the family $X_n$ is equi-integrable and $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability then:

- $X$ is integrable and $E|X_n-X| \rightarrow 0$.

Equi-integrable means that the function:
   $$ M(R) = \sup_n E \left( |X_n| 1_{|X_n|>R} \right) = \sup_n \int_{|X_n|>R} |X_n| \; dP$$
goes to zero as $R\rightarrow \infty$.